# Model change not getting reflected in view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have got a main index page, in which i initially hide the footer bar. But i want to display it when some item is clicked in some child view. I can see in the logs the model is getting changed, but its not getting reflected in the view.

index page:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane ng-controller="AudioCtrl">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-content></ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar ng-hide="musicBar.hide">
        <div class="audio-block">
            .....
        </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-pane>
</body>
```

The child view page:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="AudioCtrl as controller" title="{{selectedCategory}}">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="$parent.songClicked()">{{item.desc}}</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The angular code:

```
app.controller('AudioCtrl', function ($sce, $scope) {
        $scope.musicBar= {
            hide: true
        };
        $scope.songClicked = function(){
            console.log($scope.musicBar.hide);
            $scope.musicBar.hide = false;
            console.log($scope.musicBar.hide);
        };
    }

);
```

When i click the item i can see musicBar.hide changing from true to false, but its not reflected in the view. I have also check other similar questions but the solution doesn't work. I have tried using $scope.$digest() and $scope.$apply(), but then i get apply already in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index.html and the cub view are each managed by their own instance of AudioCtrl, each having their own scope.

The header is made visible when the main view scope's `musicBar.hide` becomes true, but that never happens, because the subview  doesn't modify it. It modifies the sub view scope's `musicBar.hide` variable.

I don't see any reason why a sub view would have the same controller as the main view. It shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks, using $emit and $on worked with two different controllers for them.